# Indefinite integral of $1/x$: two different constant terms on each side of the y-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose we have a piecewise-defined function $f$ such that
$$x<0 \implies f(x) = \ln -x + c_1 \implies f'(x) = -\frac1{-x} = \frac1x$$
$$x>0 \implies f(x) = \ln x + c_2 \implies f'(x) = \frac1x$$

Then by the definition of antidifferentiation, $f(x)$ is a solution of $\int\frac1xdx$. However, in math class, what I have been told was that $\int \frac1x dx = \ln |x| +c$, with only one constant term. Is there in fact a constraint on the two constant terms such that they have to be equal, to result in the simplification to a single constant term, or is the one-constant solution just not general?

Comment: In elementary calculus, one is taught that $f'(x)=0$ implies that $f$ is constant. Experienced mathematicians realise that $f$ is only locally constant; this distinction is considered too subtle for beginners.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you mean for some values of $x$ or do you mean for all $x$? Also how does that relate to this question?

Comment: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/03/reader_survey_logx_c.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant terms on the two sides of a discontinuity can be different.  This is clear by looking at the graph: you can shift up and down the graphs of the two sides independently without affecting the derivative.

Comment: Does this mean the solution given in my math class is not general enough?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it means.